# How to test Event Listeners in Camunda?

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have used Execution and Task Listener in my process. How to unit test them using Junit in Camunda.

Comment: What do you want to test? Only your code of the execution listener? Or the integration with the camunda engine?

Comment: The integration with the engine. I am testing the whole process definition,I have a task listener which connects to an External URL and gets the response and according to that response my process flow goes on. So here I am unable to mock that response which presents in TaskListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use for example the [Camunda Model API](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-model) and write a unit test to test your Execution listener.

The unit test could look like the following:

```
  @Test
  public void testEndExecutionListenerIsCalledOnlyOnce() {

    BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess("process")
      .startEvent()
      .userTask()
      .camundaExecutionListenerClass(ExecutionListener.EVENTNAME_END, TestingExecutionListener.class.getName())
      .endEvent()
      .done();

    testHelper.deploy(modelInstance);

    // given
    ProcessInstance procInst = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("process");
    TaskQuery taskQuery = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(procInst.getId());

    //when task is completed
    taskService.complete(taskQuery.singleResult().getId());

    // then end listener is called
    // assert something for example a variable is set or something else
  }
```

For more examples see how Camunda tests the Execution Listeners in
[ExecutionListenerTest.java](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/test/bpmn/executionlistener/ExecutionListenerTest.java).